# Regular audio crackling/cpu spikes when connected to wifi?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, audio, laptop-repair

I've had this problem for several weeks now, and haven'n managed to find a fix for it.
It usually happens every 5-10 minutes, specially while watching a youtube video or using any thing which needs the internet (only on wifi. ethernet cable works fine).

I'm running windows 7 home premium with a intel n100 wifi card. Whenever it happens I also notice a loading symbol on the connectivity icon at the bottom right taskbar(connection does not get interrupted).

I was wondering if anyone has come across a fix for this?
What I've tried so far:
-replacing wifi card
-updating/rolling back driver
-Monitoring/ Removing unused programs/processes in task manager

(edit: This is on an Asus n55sf laptop by the way)

Comment: When you say you have tried replacing the card.  Did you try another manufacture?  Intel has a habit of not having the best WifI equipment.

Comment: no, I replaced it with another intel card, but I doubt the card would be the problem, or it would have worked. Haven't noticed this problem till a few weeks ago. I've seen several others report similar problems, but no pinpoint solutions